# formating each string comming out of Grep

Tags: shell, unix, file-io

**this is homework!**

im writing a shell script that will essentially create a database of books the file that holds all the books that have been input looks like

J.K. Rowling:Harry Potter:I Dont Know:200s'
Author(s)1:title1:Publisher1:year1
Author(s)2:title2:Publisher2:year2
.
.
.
Author(s)(n):title(n):Publisher(n):year(n)

now im using grep to search for a particular search pattern that is input in the command line lets say "Harry Potter", it will then output all the entries with the string "Harry potter in it"

i have that working with

```
grep $2 "bookprint.txt"
```

however it prints everything out the same as it was entered into the file soo....  Author(s)1:title1:Publisher1:year1

i however would like to format the string so it will print 4 separate lines separated into 2 columns per line so the output would look like

Author(S):..J.K. Rowling
Title:...........Harry Potter
Publisher:...I dont know
Year:..........2000's
(pretend the periods are blank spaces i couldn't format them correctly to show what i wanted)

any tips here would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only sed and grep:

```
grep "$2" "bookprint.txt" | sed 's/^/Author(s)! /; s/:/\nTitle!     /; s/:/\nPublisher! /; s/:/\nYear!      /; s/!/:/g'
```

Testing it on your example to show sample output from the sed command:

```
$ echo "J.K. Rowling:Harry Potter:I dont know:2000's" | sed 's/^/Author(s)! /; s/:/\nTitle!     /; s/:/\nPublisher! /; s/:/\nYear!      /; s/!/:/g' 
Author(s): J.K. Rowling
Title:     Harry Potter
Publisher: I dont know
Year:      2000's
```

**How it works:**  sed makes five substitutions.  In general, each substitution works looks like `s/old/new/'.  This instructs sed to find the first occurrence of "old" and replace it with "new".  Thus, for example:

```
$ echo "this is so old" | sed 's/old/new/'
this is so new
```

The first one substitute that we use is:

```
s/^/Author(s)! /
```

For sed, the caret (`^`) is a special character and it matches the beginning of the line.  Thus, this substitute causes the "Author(s)! " to be placed at the beginning of the line.

The second substitute command is

```
s/:/\nTitle!     /
```

This causes the first occurrence of colon (":") to be replaced by "\nTitle!     " where `\n` is treated as a newline character.

If we had just used those two commands, the result would be:

```
$ echo "J.K. Rowling:Harry Potter:I dont know:2000's" | sed 's/^/Author(s)! /; s/:/\nTitle!     /' 
Author(s)! J.K. Rowling
Title!     Harry Potter:I dont know:2000's
```

So, we still need to put in the publisher and the year.

Look at the output above and you will see that, after having done the two substitutions above, the first colon appears just before the publisher's name. So, the third substitute command is:

```
s/:/\nPublisher! /
```

This command causes the first occurrence of colon (":") to be replaced with "\nPublisher! ".   The line for year is created the same way with the substitution:

```
s/:/\nYear!      /
```

With just those four substitutions, we would have:

```
$ echo "J.K. Rowling:Harry Potter:I dont know:2000's" | sed 's/^/Author(s)! /; s/:/\nTitle!     /; s/:/\nPublisher! /; s/:/\nYear!      /' 
Author(s)! J.K. Rowling
Title!     Harry Potter
Publisher! I dont know
Year!      2000's
```

This looks fine except that we have exclamation points where we need colons.  So, the last substitution we need is:

```
s/!/:/g
```

Notice the "g" at the end.  That tells sed to make this substitution globally.  Thus, this substitution tells sed to replace *every* exclamation point with a colon.  This gives the result you wanted.

Comment: Wow Thanks! im new to shell all the slashes and stuff still confuse me, can u recommend a good guide/website where i can read what say "s/^/Author(s)! /;" does exactly and how it works so i can create something like this in the future?

Comment: @cooooookiemonster  I've added an explanation as a start.  For more on the basics, an introduction to bash is [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/) and an introduction to sed is [here](http://evc-cit.info/cit052/sed_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to try `gawk` for this kind of task (although it can be done with pure `bash`). With `gawk` you can do it like:

```
gawk -v SEARCH="${2}" -F ":" '$0 ~ SEARCH {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { print $i }}'
```

1. This passes your searchstring to `gawk` (`-v SEARCH="${2}`)
2. Set the input files' field separator (`-F ":"`)
3. Searches every line (`$0`) for your searchstring
4. For every matches prints every field from that line on a separate line

Without `gawk` (and `sed`):

```
IFS=":" read -a array <<< $(grep $2 bookprint.txt)
for element in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$element"
done
```

***Note*** it only works if there is only one matching record. It is doable with more records, *but* we are not here to solve your homework. You should research and try solutions yourself. And read the fine manuals. And learn.

Comment: i don't think im allowed to use that command i think im only allowed to work with find, sed and grep

Comment: It can be done with sed.  I will see if I can ffigure out an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need anything except the shell to parse and format:

```
grep "$2" bookprint.txt | while IFS=: read -r author title publisher year; do
    echo "Author(S):  $author"
    echo "Title:      $title"
    echo "Publisher:  $publisher"
    echo "Year:       $year"
done
```

**Very** important to quote the `"$2"` in the grep command: if $2 contains "Harry Potter", grep will give you an error like "no such file: Potter" (assuming you do not have a file named Potter)